# Android Studio, after running the app to mobile device, it replaced the last app and so on (those apps are different)

Tags: java, android, debugging, mobile

Android Studio, after running the app to mobile device, it replaced the last app and so on (those apps are different). So in my mobile device I have several apps (I'm not a beginner), but today is The Day when every time when I run/build an app to my mobile device from Android Studio it replaced the last one ... and so on ... I have enough space on device ... Some ideas?

Comment: Are you using same package names? You have to provide a lot more information, enough to find an answer

Comment: Thank you! You're the best!!! I had the same package names :D, really funny...

Comment: glad it worked :)